# how to make a table row contents to break lline?

Tags: php, html

I want my table row to break line . Below is my code I have used. I don't want all contents to be in the same lime. How to do it?

```
<?php

echo "<table width='50%'  table-layout: fixed; style='border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 20px' ><tr>";
   foreach ($cursor as $document) {

echo "<td align='center' valign='center'>"; 

$value=$document["rootFolder"];
$value2=$document["uploadSize"];

$_SESSION['rootFolder']=$value;

  echo '<input type="image" src="images/file2.png" value="'.$value.'" class="btTxt submit" width="85" onclick="myfunc('.$value2 .',this.value)"><b> <br /> '.$value . "</b>";
echo "</td>";

}

echo "</tr></table>";

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "break line"? Do you mean when you look at the source?

Comment: like to change line instead of having all the contents displayed in one table row..

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question. What line do you want to change? Can you show us what you have and what you would like to have?

Comment: actually. in my web page, via the code above, images are diplayed along with their names. but i want the names to be displayed just below the pictures and also after 4 pictures being displayed, i want the next picture to change line. with the code above, all the pictures are in the same line but i want it to break after 4 or 3 pictures

Comment: Do you mean every 4th `td` should start on a new line?

Comment: I have linked you to an answer

Comment: yes 4th on next line